# plt.boxplot draws fliers despite setting sym = ''

Tags: python, matplotlib

According to the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot):

> Enter an empty string (‘’) if you don’t want to show fliers.

However, the following code:

```
plt.boxplot(([1,2,3,4, 200],  [5,10,23, 42, 300]), sym = '')
```

Produces:

[image]

Fliers are obviously there. Is this a bug? am I doing something wrong?

(python 2.7.8, mpl 1.4.0)

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Python 2.7.8 and matplotlib 1.4.2. You could try the option `showfliers=False`. Also if you print the `plt.boxplot (..., sym='')` line, what does it say at `fliers`? Mine says (and it should say) `'fliers': []`.

Comment: See: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3459, that issue is already reported - and fixed: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3533

Comment: @cel Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @tcaswell, done. However next time feel free to post an answer yourself. After all, you implemented the fix and probably know best what went wrong :)

Comment: but I am lazy and don't need the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is a regression which was fixed in `matplotlib` `v1.4.1`. You can find more information about the issue in [salspaugh's ticket](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3459) and also in
[tcaswell's fix](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3533) at `github`.

As mentioned in the comments passing `showfliers=False` to the `boxplot` method is another neat option to hide the outliers.